# Which version of spring data mongo db with mongo java driver 3.0.2 and spring framework 3.2.2.Release

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Which version of spring data mongo DB can support mongo java driver 3.0.2 and spring framework version of 3.2.2.RELEASE.

I already have implementation of the mongo java driver 3.0.2 in the codebase. Wanted to leverage the code of spring  data for further development.

Answer (score 2):

As per Spring Data MongoDB documentation it looks like 1.8.4 support Mongo 3.0 upwards. Check this url http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.8.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#new-features.1-7-0

Now Spring 3.2 is quite old so not sure if you will have any issues with that.